# XPath Specific Expression WebDriver Error

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have a problem with WebDriver's XPath that, even though it's right, is returning an error expression.

The expression is:

`(*//div[contains(@class, 'myb-SettledBetItem ') or contains(@class, 'myb-OpenBetItem_Collapsed') or contains(@class, 'myb-OpenBetItem ')]//(span[@class='myb-SettledBetParticipant_ParticipantSpan ' or @class='myb-OpenBetParticipant_ParticipantSpan']|div[@class='myb-SettledBetItem_SubHeaderText']))`

The html is:

```
<div class="myb-BetItemsContainer_BetItemsContainer ">
    <div class="myb-SettledBetItem ">
        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader ">
            <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader_HeaderTextContainer ">
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader_Title ">
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader_Text ">R$0,50 Simples</div>
                </div>
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_SubHeaderText "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_BetStateContainer ">
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_BetStateLabel ">Retorno Obtido</div>
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_BetReturnLabel ">R$1,19</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant-FirstOfType myb-SettledBetParticipant myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won ">
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_Header ">
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_HeaderTitle ">
                            <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_HeaderText "><span class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_ParticipantSpan ">Hollyoak Hector (v Courts Ad Darcey) </span>
                                <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill myb-HalfAndHalfPill_Status-1 ">
                                    <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatus myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatus-1 ">
                                        <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusLHS myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusLHS-1 "></div>
                                        <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusRHS myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusRHS-1 "></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_HeaderOdds ">2.37</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_MarketDescription ">Aposta Comparativa</div>
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_FixtureDescription ">8.27 Central Park EVE (Corrida 8)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter ">
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_BetInformation ">
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeInformation ">
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeLabel ">Aposta</div>
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeTextWrapper "><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeTextCurrency myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeTextCurrency-formatted ">R$</span><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeText ">0,50</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnInformation ">
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnLabel ">Retorno Total</div>
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnTextWrapper "><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnTextCurrency myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnTextCurrency-formatted ">R$</span><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnText ">1,19</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myb-SettledBetItem ">
        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader ">
            <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader_HeaderTextContainer ">
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader_Title ">
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetItemHeader_Text ">R$0,50 Simples</div>
                </div>
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_SubHeaderText "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_BetStateContainer ">
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_BetStateLabel ">Retorno Obtido</div>
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItem_BetReturnLabel ">R$0,77</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant-FirstOfType myb-SettledBetParticipant myb-SettledBetParticipant_Won ">
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_Header ">
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_HeaderTitle ">
                            <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_HeaderText "><span class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_ParticipantSpan ">Trap 8 </span>
                                <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill myb-HalfAndHalfPill_Status-1 ">
                                    <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatus myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatus-1 ">
                                        <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusLHS myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusLHS-1 "></div>
                                        <div class="myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusRHS myb-HalfAndHalfPill_TextStatusRHS-1 "></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_HeaderOdds ">1.53</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_MarketDescription ">Vencedor e V/C Ao-Vivo</div>
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetParticipant_FixtureDescription ">Race 15 Palm Beach</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter ">
                <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_BetInformation ">
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeInformation ">
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeLabel ">Aposta</div>
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeTextWrapper "><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeTextCurrency myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeTextCurrency-formatted ">R$</span><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_StakeText ">0,50</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnInformation ">
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnLabel ">Retorno Total</div>
                        <div class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnTextWrapper "><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnTextCurrency myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnTextCurrency-formatted ">R$</span><span class="myb-SettledBetItemFooter_ReturnText ">0,77</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected outcome:

1. Hollyoak Hector (v Courts Ad Darcey)
2. Trap 8

And was tested on the site: http://xpather.com/

The error returned is:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression THIS_EXPRESSION because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string THIS_EXPRESSION  is not a valid XPath expression. .... in DIR/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php on line 152

What is happening? Why doesn't it work in WebDriver's Xpath and it works on this site?
Is this the best way to handle this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath expression only works in XPath-2.0 or above.
To make it work in XPath-1.0, you have to split what you have tried to do with the brackets:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'myb-SettledBetItem ') or contains(@class, 'myb-OpenBetItem_Collapsed') or contains(@class, 'myb-OpenBetItem ')]//span[@class='myb-SettledBetParticipant_ParticipantSpan ' or @class='myb-OpenBetParticipant_ParticipantSpan'] | //div[contains(@class, 'myb-SettledBetItem ') or contains(@class, 'myb-OpenBetItem_Collapsed') or contains(@class, 'myb-OpenBetItem ')]/div[@class='myb-SettledBetItem_SubHeaderText']
```

So duplicate the first part of the expression and apply the union afterwards on both expressions.